# BCS Model not deploying in Farm environment

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, bdc-model

Has anyone else seen an issue with deploying a BCS Model WSP to a farm and the External Content Type is not being deployed? The Farm feature is activated.

It is working fine for a single server scenario but as soon as there are multiple servers it doesn't want to play nice

Answer (score 1):

Check the sharepoint logs on the servers when you deploy the solution to see if there were any errors deploying the external content type.

Make sure all of the timer jobs are complete too, it might take a while to deploy and refresh.